# How to toggle word wrap in Visual Studio's immediate window?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to toggle the wordwrap in the immediate window of Visual Studio? I have searched a lot. I could see the word wrap only for the code window. It is inconvenient to scroll right every time to see the hidden text.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Click into the Immediate Window, hold the Control key and press E and then W: tested on VS2022 Professional.

Source: [MicrosoftDocs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio.md)